# How to change the package name of my app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, package

I created a project in Android Studio. Android Studio generated a package name according to my app name. But I don't want that name (`com.randompasswordgenerator`). So I found all the occurences of the package name and changed it to `com.passwordgen`. However, when I run the app, in the `Run` console, it still uses the old name:

```
Installing com.randompasswordgenerator
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.randompasswordgenerator"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.randompasswordgenerator
Success
...
```

I tried to change the package name in the manifest but it is already automatically changed to the new name. I guess there is another place that I need to change the name, but where?

I know this has been asked a lot of times. But the posts I found uses Eclipse instead of Android Studio.

EDIT:

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.passwordgen" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GenerateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_generate"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OptionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_options"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_password"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you change the name do it using the refactoring option in Android studio (right click on the package, and click rename). Then the reason you will still see the old package is that Android Studio has not detected any code changes, and is just giving you the package that is already built. You can change this by doing a `project clean`. Please comment if you have any issues

[image]

Comment: what is a `project clean`? Is it something about gradle?

Comment: Sorry I mean clean project. It can be found under the build menu. I will attach a screenshot to the answer

Comment: No, it still says the same thing when I run the app. You say that android studio has not detected any code changes but my code _did_ change! I see all my java files are in the `com.passwordgen` package.

Comment: stupid question, have you tried closing and opening Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I did! still says the same thing.

Comment: and build.gradle as well.

Comment: Oh I see! So I need to change the gradle build file! It's so weird that android studio didn't do that for me.

Comment: Make sure that when you rename/move a package, you also check the search in comments and strings checkbox, or it won't modify the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Click with right button on your `com.randompasswordgenerator` folder and go to

Refactor>Rename (Shift + F6), than change to whatever you like!!!

Don't forget to Rename others locations that you "call" your package name!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also programmatically specify the applicationId

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.passwordgen'
    }
}
```

this changes the outputted code but doesn't affect the original source directory paths

Answer (score 0):

[Changing Project Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCyWX.jpg)

I am saying what has worked for me.

I have tried to change the Project Name/App name in Android Studio with Refactor option. But "Can not change project name/root folder" pop up comes.

Then I closed the project in android stuio (Android Studio is still not closed), then i changed the project folder name from `DipCalculator` to `DipCalculator2`.
Then I changed package name in all java code occurrences in app/src. Then app/build.gradle, app/app.iml file. [changing project name in build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWRIO.jpg). I did not distrubed any other folders/files other than what i mentioned

Then I reopened the project from Android Studio, Then Build Synch. Then i build the apk & run it on my phone. New installation showed new app name `DipCalculator2` instead of `DipCalculator`.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean project then go to Manifexst.XML and search where says android `label="@/String_appname"` and delete it.
for example : `android label="NEW"`
regards!